# My Dell laptop Inspiron 6000 won't go past the logo page

Tags: 14.04, laptop

Please I really need help. I was trying to get the new update Ubuntu 14.02 I think and I forced it to quit then i logged off and tried to to sign back into my account and that didn't work so I restarted it several times and now it won't go past the logo page please I really need help it's my first laptop.

Comment: Wait 60 seconds. Then it should pass the bios logo.

Comment: what do you mean by "logo page"?  The manufacturer logo at BIOS or the Ubuntu logo which is the splash screen typically seen when Ubuntu is actually loading?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the steps:

1) when it is on the Ubuntu logo page where comes 4 dots that shows loading, press ESC on keyboard, you will see everything that is running there at the start of the Ubuntu, you will eventually see the program that is taking or halting the system, you can tell us that operation.

2) when the grub loads in, goto "Advanced versions" if this version is not there then this might be there-> "PREVIOUS VERSIONS OF UBUNTU", then select a previous kernel, your system will be loaded there, if you get through log in and see your desktop then

a) copy all your essential data in case of worst case scenario.

b) try restarting the system normally into your default kernel, if success then Voila! :P

3) Download the latest kernel iso, make a bootable usb, and when you get to the installation type, select "upgrade ubuntu 14" and in this way you MAY save your data and your ubuntu.

4) WORST CASE SCENARIO: you might have to reinstall ubuntu, the thing is you can have your data and that depends if you want to proceed, if yes, then please let me know I will provide you necessary steps to get through it..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24122/discussion-on-answer-by-shymad-my-dell-laptop-inspiron-6000-wont-go-past-the-log).